# Getting rid of Timestamp in order to insert data into sql table

Tags: python, pandas

I am having issues inserting this dataframe into a sql table due to the 'DATE' variable. I need to get rid of the Timestamp that shows up when I change it to a tuple

[image]

[image]

Getting tuple from df to use in sql insert

[image]

What is the best way to get rid of the 'Timestamp('DATE') and have only 'DATE'?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the possible ways of doing this is to convert `datetime64` to `String` that contains only 'DATE', in order to do this you can use `datetime_as_string` function from numpy :

```
import numpy as np

df['DATE'] = np.datetime_as_string(df['DATE'], unit='D')
```

then your code will work correctly.

Comment: how can it be done , if there are several datetime fields and is not known in advance?

Comment: @renjith you can read the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.datetime_as_string.html)